# How to create datasets for all labels for stacked bar in chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I'm creating a graph with chart.js that has 2 series(count1 and count2) and multiple labels on the x-axis.

for the series I have created 2 datasets, but when I set the labels only the first one is created with 2 colors, the rest takes the default colors.

How to make all the bars take the colors of the dataset series?

So far this is what I have done:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart")

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: "bar",
  data: {
  labels: ['Product 1','Product 2','Product 3','Product 4','Product 5','Product 6'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Count 1',
      data: [10,2,2,2,0,1],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
      ]
    }, {
      label: 'Count 2',
      data: [10,5,1,0,5,4],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Example in JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/espinoza/uzjyrfv2/

Answer (score 0):

The colors of my dataset were inside brackets, that was causing it to be taken as an array, I left only the value.

I hope this helps someone else.

```js
              
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart")

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: "bar",
  data: {
  labels: ['Product 1','Product 2','Product 3','Product 4','Product 5','Product 6'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Count 1',
      data: [10,2,2,2,0,1],
      backgroundColor: 
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
    }, {
      label: 'Count 2',
      data: [10,5,1,0,5,4],
      backgroundColor: 
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Attached link in JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/espinoza/uzjyrfv2/1/